# Conflict bootstrap-javascript in my html page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have this easy page in html, css and some components in bootstrap. I wanna make a dialog popup that I can open with button click.

without bootstrap link it works well but when I add bootstrap on header I see the dialog in background on my page as you can see in photo[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TTQg.png)

I show my html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Attività Standard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="attivita.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="firstnav">
        <form action="logout.html">
            <button class="logout"><img src="assets/icons8-uscita-50.png" alt="" srcset="" class="logoutimg"></button>
        </form>
        <img src="./assets/icons8-notifiche-32.png" alt="" srcset="" class="logoutimg">
        <button id="showPanel" class="notification">Notifiche</button>
        <input class="searchbar" type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="Cerca">
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar navbar-dark bg-dark" style="margin-top: 3vw;">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText" style="margin-left: 28vw;">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Dashboard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="attivita.html">Attività Standard</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="extra.html">Attività extra</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Archivio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Materiali</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Manuale</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">FAQ</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <img src="./assets/icons8-utente-uomo-cerchiato-24.png" alt="" srcset=""
                        style="width: 90%;height: 70%; padding-top: 6px;">
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Utente</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <dialog id="favDialog" class="notificationpanel">
        <label class="notificationlabel">Notifiche</label>
        <img src="./assets/icons8-notifiche-32.png" alt="" srcset="" class="notifimg">

        <form>
            <button value="cancel" formmethod="dialog" style="margin-left: 60vw;"><img
                    src="./assets/icons8-eliminare-50.png" alt="" srcset="" class="closebutton"></button>
        </form>
    </dialog>
    <div style="padding-left: 40vw; padding-top: 2vw;">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Filtra per
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Ordina per
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                Reset
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="container">
            <div>
                <label style="padding-left: 2vw;"> Periodo: <b style="color: red;">Maggio</b></label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-hover color-8">Periodo precedente</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-hover color-9">Periodo successivo</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn-hover color-1">Combo selezione periodo</button>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-right: 2vw;">
                <table class="table table-striped" style="margin-left: 1vw;padding-right: 1vw;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                            <th scope="col">STATUS</th>
                            <th scope="col">DEALER</th>
                            <th scope="col">DATA</th>
                            <th scope="col">TOTALE BUDGET</th>
                            <th scope="col">PREVENTIVI CARICATI/PREVENTIVI VALIDATI</th>
                            <th scope="col">CONSUNTIVI CARICATI/CONSUNTIVI VALIDATI</th>
                            <th scope="col"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">1</th>
                            <td>In corso</td>
                            <td>Company Name</td>
                            <td>22 Giugno 2023</td>
                            <td>€200.00</td>
                            <td>3/2</td>
                            <td>3/2</td>
                            <td><img src="./assets/icons8-menu-2-24.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">2</th>
                            <td>In corso</td>
                            <td>Company Name</td>
                            <td>22 Giugno 2023</td>
                            <td>€200.00</td>
                            <td>3/2</td>
                            <td>3/2</td>
                            <td><img src="./assets/icons8-menu-2-24.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="row">3</th>
                            <td>In corso</td>
                            <td>Company Name</td>
                            <td>22 Giugno 2023</td>
                            <td>€200.00</td>
                            <td>3/2</td>
                            <td>3/2</td>
                            <td><img src="./assets/icons8-menu-2-24.png" alt="" srcset=""></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <!-- <table>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                    <th>DEALER</th>
                    <th>DATA</th>
                    <th>TOTALE BUDGET</th>
                    <th>PREVENTIVI CARICATI/PREVENTIVI VALIDATI</th>
                    <th>CONSUNTIVI CARICATI/CONSUNTIVI VALIDATI</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>In corso</td>
                    <td>Company Name</td>
                    <td>22 Giugno 2023</td>
                    <td>€200.00</td>
                    <td>3/2</td>
                    <td>3/2</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>-->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"></script>
</html>
```

my js:

```
 const showButton = document.getElementById("showPanel");
    const favDialog = document.getElementById("favDialog");
    const outputBox = document.querySelector("output");


    // "Show the dialog" button opens the <dialog> modally
    showButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
        favDialog.showModal();
    });

    // "Cancel" button closes the dialog without submitting because of [formmethod="dialog"], triggering a close event.
    favDialog.addEventListener("close", (e) => {
        outputBox.value =
            favDialog.returnValue === "default"
                ? "No return value."
                : `ReturnValue: ${favDialog.returnValue}.`;
    });

    // Prevent the "confirm" button from the default behavior of submitting the form, and close the dialog with the `close()` method, which triggers the "close" event.
    confirmBtn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); // We don't want to submit this fake form
        favDialog.close(selectEl.value); // Have to send the select box value here.
    });
```

```
.searchbar {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: url('./assets/icon-ricerca.png') no-repeat scroll;
    background-size: 1vw, 1vw;
    background-position: 5% 50%;
    padding-left: 30px;
    left: 40vw;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5vw;
}

.kia {
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    margin-right: 13vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    float: left;
}

.alist {
    margin-left: 12vw;
    padding-top: 5px;
}



.notification {
    float: right;
    top: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    margin-right: 1vw;
    padding-top: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 1px;
    font-size: x-small;
}

.logout {
    float: right;
    top: 0%;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    margin-right: 5vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logoutimg {
    height: 2vw;
    width: 2vw;
    float: right;
    top: 1vw;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    margin-right: 5vw;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.firstnav {
    padding-top: 1vw;
}



.navbarelements {
    font-size: x-small;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a {
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0.5;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 2vw;
    font-size: small;
}

body {
    font: 16px/1.4 sans-serif;
}

.notificationpanel{
    height : 45vw ;
    width: 80vw;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: none;
  }
  
.closebutton {
  height: 1vw;
  width: 1vw;
  float: left;
  top: 0%;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.notifimg {
  height: 2vw;
  width: 2vw;
  float: left;
  top: 1vw;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-right: 1vw;
}

.notificationlabel{ 
  float: left;
  top: 1vw;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  margin-right: 1vw;
  top: 1px;
  font-size:medium;
}



.card {
    /* Add shadows to create the "card" effect */
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 80vw;
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 12vw;
    margin-top: 3vw;
}

/* Add some padding inside the card container */
.container {
    padding-left: 1vw;
    padding-top: 2vw;
    padding-right: 3vw;
}

th {
 font-size: small;
}

td {
 font-size: small;
}

.btn-hover.color-8 {
    background-color: gray;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin-left: 25vw;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background-size: 1vw, 1vw;
    background-position: 5% 50%;
    width: 12vw;
    height: 2vw;
    font-size: x-small;
    border: none;
}

.cardsummary{
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.3s;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 25vw;
    margin-left: 12vw;
    background-color: #edf2f7;
    display: inline-block
}

.btn-hover.color-9 {
    border: none;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: white;
    background-size: 1vw, 1vw;
    background-position: 5% 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 12vw;
    height: 2vw;
    font-size: x-small;
}

.btn-hover.color-1 {
    background-color: gray;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 25px;
border: none;
    background-size: 1vw, 1vw;
    background-position: 5% 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 12vw;
    height: 2vw;
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

Comment: Try put the HTML for your dialog at the end of the HTML page, that way it comes after the table, or, on top of it. Alternatively, you could set a [z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for the dialog.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware with your solution I continue to see the dialog on the background It shouldn't see when I'vo not clicked the button

Comment: I make [a CodePen](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/zYMbPgv) for you. First of all I moved the dialog down. Then I added the style `#favDialog { display: none; }` so the dialog doesn't show. Now when you press "Notifiche" the dialog will show, by using `favDialog.style.display = 'block';`.

Comment: Thank you I've already solved with something like that so I sign your answer as correct